# Django - loop through through records and update the record inside the loop?

Tags: django

I cant seem to find the documentation for this, but I want to update the record within a loop of a QuerySet example:

```
data = Site.objects.all()
for i in data:
 ... do stuff
 i.update(field="value")
```

I know I could do it by:

```
data = Site.objects.all()
for i in data:
 ... do stuff
 Site.objects.filter(pk=i.pk).update(field="value")
```

but this seems inefficient as I already have the record, so shouldn't need to query for it again?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to update field for every object with the same value `Site.objects.all().update(field='value')` should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `save`:

```
data = Site.objects.all()
for i in data:
    # ... do stuff
    # i.update(field="value")
    i.field = value
    i.save()
```

n.b., updating objects in a loop is woefully expensive, especially for a large number of objects.  And, no matter what, the save will cost you an additional query.

Comment: its used for a monitoring script that periodically gathers data for all my sites an then updates the records, so I guess speed doesnt matter that much, would you recommend leaving it as is or using save?

Comment: Up to you.  using `update` does allow you to aggregate common updates, but using save is a lot easier to understand.

Comment: what if I need the queryset itself to be updated?? this code will update data in the database and does not change values inside query itself. @2ps

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow?  In the code above, we're looping over the query set and changing the values in the models that are in the query set.

Comment: Whats the best solution for this ?

Comment: you can use [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) to update all those objects at once. @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris